# How do I convert a json that contains a LocalDate field to deserializable format?

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson, jsr310

I have an object stored in a String. One of the object's fields is a LocalDate.

```
"from": {
        "year": 1000,
        "month": "JANUARY",
        "era": "CE",
        "dayOfMonth": 1,
        "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
        "dayOfYear": 1,
        "leapYear": false,
        "monthValue": 1,
        "chronology": {
            "calendarType": "iso8601",
            "id": "ISO"
        }
    }
```

How should I go about converting this json to a format that can be used for deserializing it?

The following code

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;


ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
MyCustomObject obj = om.readValue(json, MyCustomObject.class); //error
```

causes this Exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING: Expected array or string.
```

Here's the MyCustomObject class which I use as MyCustomObject<LocalDate>

```
public class MyCustomObject<T> {
    private T from;
    private T to;

    public MyCustomObject() {
    }

    public T getFrom() {
        return this.from;
    }

    public void setFrom(T from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public T getTo() {
        return this.to;
    }

    public void setTo(T to) {
        this.to = to;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `MyCustomObject` code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LocalDate` is stored in incorrectly in the JSON.

The correct way to fix the problem is to ensure that the `ObjectMapper` generating the JSON has the [`JavaTimeModule`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310) or the [`Jdk8Module`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) registered. This ensures that the `LocalDate` is correctly serialized to a JSON array of `[year, month, day]`.

The brute-force method is to follow the solution that @Roy outlined in another answer, and convert each relevant field manually to a `LocalDate`. Something along the lines of :

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now()
        .with(ChronoField.YEAR, year)
        .with(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, Month.valueOf(month).getValue())
        .with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
```

This is obviously rather error-prone, and not how the classes were intended to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your MyCustomObject.class like this:

```
==================================
package ;
public class Chronology
{
    private String calendarType;

    private String id;

    public void setCalendarType(String calendarType){
        this.calendarType = calendarType;
    }
    public String getCalendarType(){
        return this.calendarType;
    }
    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
}

==================================
package ;
public class From
{
    private int year;

    private String month;

    private String era;

    private int dayOfMonth;

    private String dayOfWeek;

    private int dayOfYear;

    private boolean leapYear;

    private int monthValue;

    private Chronology chronology;

    public void setYear(int year){
        this.year = year;
    }
    public int getYear(){
        return this.year;
    }
    public void setMonth(String month){
        this.month = month;
    }
    public String getMonth(){
        return this.month;
    }
    public void setEra(String era){
        this.era = era;
    }
    public String getEra(){
        return this.era;
    }
    public void setDayOfMonth(int dayOfMonth){
        this.dayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
    }
    public int getDayOfMonth(){
        return this.dayOfMonth;
    }
    public void setDayOfWeek(String dayOfWeek){
        this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
    }
    public String getDayOfWeek(){
        return this.dayOfWeek;
    }
    public void setDayOfYear(int dayOfYear){
        this.dayOfYear = dayOfYear;
    }
    public int getDayOfYear(){
        return this.dayOfYear;
    }
    public void setLeapYear(boolean leapYear){
        this.leapYear = leapYear;
    }
    public boolean getLeapYear(){
        return this.leapYear;
    }
    public void setMonthValue(int monthValue){
        this.monthValue = monthValue;
    }
    public int getMonthValue(){
        return this.monthValue;
    }
    public void setChronology(Chronology chronology){
        this.chronology = chronology;
    }
    public Chronology getChronology(){
        return this.chronology;
    }
}

==================================
package ;
public class MyCustomObject
{
    private From from;

    public void setFrom(From from){
        this.from = from;
    }
    public From getFrom(){
        return this.from;
    }
}
```